# Servlet's doGet not called from JSP form

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have this code on my JSP page

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="username" /> 
    <input type="text" name="password" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and when I press Submit I get:

> The page cannot be displayed  The page
>   you are looking for is currently
>   unavailable. The Web site might be
>   experiencing technical difficulties,
>   or you may need to adjust your browser
>   settings.

and `LoginServlet.doGet` method doesn't get called.
But then when I press Enter again (in address bar) my `doGet` method gets called.

What is wrong? I am using Java EE eclipse and Tomcat

Comment: How about when you test it with a real webbrowser? E.g. [Firefox](http://getfirefox.com).

Comment: That error message looks specific to Internet Explorer and IE has a number of reasons why it might display that message (e.g. http://www.internetfixes.com/readers_questions/IF01710.htm).  As @BalusC suggests, having an alternate browser on hand is a good tool for helping determine whether the problem is the browser or the web server.  Try it and update your question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

What's in your web.xml file?

You WEB-INF/web.xml file needs to associate the LoginServlet specified in the JSP with the Java class LoginServlet. (For clarity I have changed the name of values.)

So if in your JSP you have

```
<form action="jspAction" method="get"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

and your Java class is

```
package com.me

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void goGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
     HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
  {
     //your code
  }
}
```

Your web.xml file would have

```
<web-app>
    <!-- Standard Action Servlet Configuration -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myServletName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.me.LoginAction</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Standard Action Servlet Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myServletName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>jspAction</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

So the web.xml file will associate myServletName with the servlet class com.me.LoginAction. Then any requests to http://localhost:8080/myApp/jspAction will be directed to myServletName and eventually to com.me.LoginAction.